# What is the most efficient cross-process communication method for IIS web services

Tags: wcf, iis, asmx, 32bit-64bit

We have a set of (ASMX but could be WCF) **64-bit web services** which need to execute some **32-bit managed code** (the APIs have 32-bit COM dependencies and cannot be executed in 64-bit) for processing on **the same physical machine**. The 64-bit web services are hosted in IIS 7.0. Note: some of the messages contain large byte arrays.

What is the most efficient way to set this up? **WCF with named pipes and binary serialization** of the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Use Named pipes if it is all on one machine.  Use binary serialization if you have large byte arrays.